# Group attribute in Coldfusion not working right

Tags: sql, coldfusion, group-by

I'm trying to display options for homes and the categories in which they're in. Formatted in this way:

```
Category 1 Category 2
---------- ----------
option 1   Option 2
```

I have gotten very close. The options are showing up as expected, but the categories are repeating themselves. I've included an image.

### [image: Repeating categories]

I've tried all combinations of group in the CFOUTPUT and in the SQL with no success. I would appreciate some ideas. This is my current code:

```
<cfquery datasource="applewood" name="categorize">
    SELECT idOptions
           , options.option
           , options.idOpCategories
           , op_categories.categoryName
    FROM  options, op_categories
    GROUP BY idOptions
</cfquery>

 ...
<cfoutput query="categorize" group="idOpCategories">
    <h3>#UCASE(categoryName)#</h3>
    <ul>
        <cfoutput>
            <li>#option#</li>
        </cfoutput>
    </ul>
</cfoutput>
```

**Update:**

I ordered and grouped by the same column and getting this result:

[image: Ordered and groupd by same column]

Comment: You need to use `ORDER BY` in the SQL and `GROUP` in the `cfoutput`

Comment: @ScottStroz, your comment is the correct answer and should be posted as such.

Comment: When I use `ORDER BY` I get what you see at [link](http://www.inter-design.net/img/categories2.jpg)

Comment: Not just any ORDER BY. You must sort the results by the same columns - in the same order - as your `cfoutput group`. Repeating generally means your query is not sorted properly. Can you please post your query? Also, what is "idOpCategories" and how does it relate to "CategoryName"?

Comment: I am thinking of making a list of Top 10 most misunderstood CF features. `cfoutput group` will definitely make the cut ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix my comment. I ordered and grouped by the same column and getting this result: [link](http://www.inter-design.net/img/newcategories.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a JOIN clause between the "options" and "op_categories" tables, so the result is an implicit CROSS JOIN or [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_join#Cross_join):

> ... it will produce rows which combine each row from the
>   first table with each row from the second table

Hence the duplicates.  You need to join the two tables on the related column ie the category id.

Also, as Scott mentioned in the comments, `cfoutput group` only [works with sorted query results](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html). However, the results must be sorted by the same columns - *in the same order* - as your grouping. Otherwise, it can create the appearance of duplicated categories.  So if you are grouping by "CategoryName" first, you should order by "CategoryName" first.

```
   SELECT cat.categoryName, o.option, ...
   FROM   options o
             INNER JOIN op_categories cat
                ON cat.idOpCategories = o.idOpCategories
   ORDER BY cat.categoryName, o.option

   <cfoutput query="..." group="categoryName">
       ... more code ...
   </cfoutput>
```

(In this specific case, you could technically use the category id as well)

Comment: I'm new to JOINS so I would never got that. Thank you!

Comment: Joins represent fundamental sql knowledge.  Since you are new to them, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: I have SQL (Database Programming) (2014 Edition). I read about Joins but I never thought I would be doing anything more complex than basic where clauses.

Comment: @PhillipPerry - Yeah, as Dan said, they are a basic element of SQL. I have never worked on an app that did not use joins. So understanding how to use them is important. Would not want to send the db server into a tailspin by forgetting a join on big tables and accidentally creating a result set of a trillion rows ;-)

Comment: If that book is a tutorial, I suggest doing every lesson - soon.  Even a slight grasp of the fundamentals is much better than fumbling about.

Comment: Each chapter has review questions. I'm just a jack of all trades kind of guy, but as I do more I need to know more. The book does have questions after each chapter. Thank you both.